# Selecting the maximum value for each raster layer in R

Tags: r, max, r-raster

I am currently trying to select the maximum value for each raster layer that I have. I have done this:

```
library(raster)
Model4 <- brick("MaxPrecCCCMACanESM2rcp45.nc", var="onedaymax")
subset<-Model4[[1:90]]
subset

class       : RasterStack 
dimensions  : 64, 128, 8192, 90  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution  : 2.8125, 2.789327  (x, y)
extent      : -181.4062, 178.5938, -89.25846, 89.25846  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
names       : X1, X2, X3, X4, X5, X6, X7, X8, X9, X10, X11, X12, X13, X14, X15, ...
```

Do derive the maximum value for each raster layer, I tried this:

```
Maxprec <- max(subset, na.rm=TRUE)
Maxprec

class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 64, 128, 8192  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 2.8125, 2.789327  (x, y)
extent      : -181.4062, 178.5938, -89.25846, 89.25846  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : layer 
values      : 1.690237, 363.9818  (min, max)
```

However, I am not sure if this is correctly selecting the maximum value for each layer - given the lowest value being shown (i.e. 1.69), I am not sure that this captures the maximum values? Ultimately, there should only be 90 maximum values (i.e. 1 maximum per layer for the 90 layers)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you aren't sure something is working, make a tiny test. Here's three small rasters where I know the max value in each:

```
> r1 = raster(matrix(1:12, 3,4))
> r2 = raster(matrix(12:23, 3,4))
> r3 = raster(matrix(23:34, 3,4))
```

make it into a brick, or a stack if you prefer:

```
> b = brick(r1,r2,r3)
```

Then to find the largest value in each layer, use `unstack` to create a list which you can loop over using any of the standard R "apply" family of functions. In this case, use `sapply`:

```
> sapply(unstack(b), function(r){max(values(r))})
[1] 12 23 34
```

and there's the largest values for each of my three layers.